# Date being sent in Selenium Webdriver (java) comes out wrong

Tags: java, date, selenium, input, webdriver

I have a small script that sends a date to an Inputfield with ID=bla.

```
@Then("^I fill in the date \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void fill_date(String date) throws Throwable {

  waitForElementPresent(By.id(bla));
  driver.findElement(By.id(bla)).click();
  driver.findElement(By.id(bla)).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.id(bla)).sendKeys(date);
  driver.findElement(By.id(Submitbutton).click();
  }
```

Now, every time I run it with, for example, date=28-06-1985, it completely messes up the date and actually sends "28-61-8590" instead of "28-06-1985". Needless to say, my test fails because the date does not exists... I also removed the Click and Clear before sending the date, but nothing seems to be working. Also, removing the stripes in the data (so sending 28061985) doesn't do anything.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to fill an input field with a date?

Comment: how do you pass the date? where is that Date object in your code above?

Comment: @EugeneS ah, good one. Added it.

Comment: Could you add the URL?

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock alas: internal use only here...

Comment: Can you fetch the element once and then interact with it, instead of finding same element everytime? I have seen this happen just once with me, it was random but I think sometimes it's the input field itself which doesn't accept "06" for month, as it converts it to "6" for clarity and maybe messes up selenium. Also, try the date "28-6-1985" and tell me what happens

Comment: @JayeshDoolani It turns it in to 28-95-816...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sending your date in three parts as below:

```
 String date1 = "28";
 String date2 = "06";
 String date3 = "1985";

  waitForElementPresent(By.id(bla));
  driver.findElement(By.id(bla)).click();
  driver.findElement(By.id(bla)).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.id(bla)).sendKeys(date1);
  driver.findElement(By.id(bla)).sendKeys(date2);
  driver.findElement(By.id(bla)).sendKeys(date3);
  driver.findElement(By.id(Submitbutton).click()
```

Comment: Strangely enough, that did the trick! Still have no clue why it would wouldn't work by just sending it in one go, but answer was given :]

Comment: Because if you insert as whole your date input box adds `-` in between and probably considers `06` as `6`, unless you provide it separately.

Comment: also tried it without the zero or the -, still mixes everything up

Comment: For a single date, yes. Still figuring out how I can input all given dates like that though...

Comment: Create a method `public String[] split_date(Sring date)` (and input your date in(22-11-2015) format then inside this method split as `String str[] = date.split("-"); return str[];`

Comment: Not quite what I meant ;) When I do something like SendKeys(2), sendkeys()8, sendkeys(-), sendkeys(0) etc, it works, your post just gave me that revelation. Now I'm just trying to have it work everytime.

Could it be my webdriver, chromedriver or other versions are not the correct ones?

Comment: When I sendKeys per character, it works everytime flawlessly. It's when I want to send an entire string it goes awry.

Comment: Yup that was the gist of it, i suppose it works fine if your date format is "26112015" with out 0 in month

Answer (score 1):

Entering text letter by letter helps me in such cases:

```
public void enterTextOneByOne(WebElement inputElement, String text){
  for (char letter : text.toCharArray()) {
    inputElement.sendKeys(CharBuffer.wrap(new char[]{letter}));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer.
I had the same issue this morning. After splitting the string it worked for some cases. But still failed for cases where month starts with 0. When I split the string in the following way, it worked. My delimiter was '/'.

```
String date1 = "05";
String date2 = "/06";
String date3 = "/1982";

driver.findElement(By.id(bla)).sendKeys(date1);
driver.findElement(By.id(bla)).sendKeys(date2);
driver.findElement(By.id(bla)).sendKeys(date3);
```

Above logic worked for me on all combinations.